# How to Run Google Cloud from Local App/Program

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, storage

We have a program that needs certain imports that can't be imported to the Google Cloud/ Cloud Shell. Is it possible to run the programs on the Cloud from somewhere in the program while sill being able to pass parameters to the functions in those programs and being able to receive information back? If not, what are some ways that we could still run certain code on the cloud and send/receive information without having to run the main program on the cloud?

The issue is we're running a GUI on the Raspberry Pi with tkinter, but we also have a neural network to run and that really doesn't need to be ran locally and runs incredibly slow. It runs a lot better on the cloud, but tkinter cannot seem to work on the cloud and we don't have time to find something else to make the GUI in.

Comment: Something like https://cloud.google.com/functions/ perhaps?

Comment: A Google Cloud Compute Engine is a Linux or Windows machine and *should* be able to run just about anything.  What I am hearing in your post if you have an app that can't run in the cloud and your ask is "how to run it in the cloud" .... I don't think this can be answered without more information.